# How do I create a User-Defined Hierarchy that includes a Parent-Child Hierarchy?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, multidimensional-array, dimensional-modeling

**Environment: SSAS 2005, BIDS 2008.**

**Data Schema**:

DepartmentMaster

- DepartmentNumber *int* (PARENT)
- SubDepartmentNumber *int* (CHILD)

CategoryMaster:

- DepartmentNumber *int references DepartmentMaster.DepartmentNumber*
- CategoryNumber *int*

**Functionality I desire:**

- Hierarchical drill down:

  - Department -> Category
  - Department -> Sub-Department -> Category

**Accomplished through the following:**

- Category Dimension
- Department Dimension

  - Parent-Child Hierarchy on Sub-Department and Department.

**Why this is a problem:**

I feel that Category really should be in the same Dimension and call it "Product" or "Item." Initially, without Sub-Department, this is how I had it set up:

- Item Dimension

  - Department -> Category

Unfortunately, once a Parent entity was introduced at the department level, I could no longer configure the attribute relationships in a way that built correctly (or at all).

**My question:**

Is it possible to configure these relationships such that they are all in one dimension giving me the Hierarchies described above?? If it is possible - should I be? Is it not working well because I'm doing it wrong to begin with?

Comment: What is the relationship between Department and Category? 1-1, 1-N, N-1, M-M?

Comment: @banton 1-N. Category can only belong to one Department, but there is no relationship to sub-department.

Comment: So the PC-hierarchy is only involving sub-department?  Can you provide the source table schema ... might help clear this confusion up?

Comment: Sure, I'll have it up in a few.

Comment: @banton Not sure what else you need, but I added some more detail to the top of the question. And you are correct. Dept and SubDept are the PC relationship. I'm guessing what I'm looking for is an Unnaturel Hierarchy here for Dept -> SubDept-> Cat. I think part of the problem is that I can't do the PC relationship on Dept/SubDept if Category is the Key for my dimension, and if Category is not the key, then the relationships don't work appropriately.

Comment: Is it a normal hierarchy? Can a subdepartment be part of two parent departments? Have you done any ELT making the data warehouse before making the dimension? I would suggest a table with redundant data with all the combinations of Department-SubDepartment-Category and a unique key and from this table to make the dimension you want

Comment: Hi Thanos, A subdepartment can only have one parent department. Your suggestion makes sense (A view would probably be better here, no?). I'll give that a shot and see how it performs